# Countdown and Points, AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript

This all works perfectly, but one thing. How do I count in ones now?
Thanks

**OUTPUT OF LIFE LOSS**
580
560
540
520
500
480
460
ect...

**OUTPUT NEEDS TO BE**
600
599
598
597
596
595
ect...'and ending with time left counter if there is no win'

**SCREENSHOT OF COUNTDOWN**

[alt text http://poizenpoprecords.com/myspace/videodnd/deltaTime.jpg](http://poizenpoprecords.com/myspace/videodnd/deltaTime.jpg)

**ActionScript**

```
//Starts with 600 life points, counts from 30-0
//game will be more intricate and retotal scores, this is just a sketch
var EQUATION:int;
var TIME:int = 30;
var COUNTDOWN:Number = 600;
var COUNTUP:Number = 0;
var START:int = getTimer();
var DELTATIME:int;
var lucky:int;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,30);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,someFunction);
myTimer.start();

function someFunction(event:TimerEvent) {
DELTATIME = (getTimer() - START)/1000;
//trace(DELTATIME);
//lucky = Math.floor(Math.random()*55);
//trace(lucky);
EQUATION = COUNTDOWN - (DELTATIME*COUNTDOWN/TIME) + COUNTUP; 
var str:String = String (Math.abs (EQUATION));
//var sub:String = ("000000")+ str.substr(0, 4);
//tx.text = String (sub);
tx.text = String ("YOU HAVE  ")+(EQUATION)+("  POINTS");
txt.text = String(Math.floor(30 - DELTATIME))+("  SECONDS LEFT");
trace(EQUATION);
if(lucky==16){
myTimer.stop(); 
var mtInter:uint = setInterval (blk, 222);
function blk():void {
txt.visible = !txt.visible;
tx.visible = !tx.visible;
txt.text = String("You're Lucky This Time");
tx.text = String("You Get 100 Life Points!");
}
}
if(EQUATION==0){
myTimer.stop(); 
var mtIntv:uint = setInterval (blink, 222);
function blink():void {
txt.visible = !txt.visible;
tx.visible = !tx.visible;
txt.text = String("Time's Up!");
tx.text = String("You're Dead!");
}
}
}
```

**SCREENSHORT OF WIN**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update function is only being called every second so at most you can display 30 values.  You want your timer to call your update function at least once for every life point. Also you used an int for the DELTA value, which rounds the number down to the nearest whole number. Changing that to the type Number let's you get decimals.

Here is your code updated to count by one although now your lucky function will be calculated more often so you will need to adjust that:

```
    //Starts with 600 life points, counts from 30-0
//game will be more intricate and retotal scores, this is just a sketch
var EQUATION:int;
var TIME:int = 30;
var COUNTDOWN:Number = 600;
var COUNTUP:Number = 0;
var START:int = getTimer();
var DELTATIME:Number;//<-- Changed this to a Number to you get more than 30 values out of it
var lucky:int;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(25); //<-- Changed the timer to repeat every 25 milliseconds and infinitely
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,someFunction);
myTimer.start();

function someFunction(event:TimerEvent) {
DELTATIME = (getTimer() - START)/1000;
//trace(DELTATIME);
//lucky = Math.floor(Math.random()*55);
//trace(lucky);
EQUATION = COUNTDOWN - (DELTATIME*COUNTDOWN/TIME) + COUNTUP; 
var str:String = String (Math.abs (EQUATION));
//var sub:String = ("000000")+ str.substr(0, 4);
//tx.text = String (sub);
tx.text = String ("YOU HAVE  ")+(EQUATION)+("  POINTS");
txt.text = String(Math.floor(30 - DELTATIME))+("  SECONDS LEFT");
trace(EQUATION);
if(lucky==16){
myTimer.stop(); 
var mtInter:uint = setInterval (blk, 222);
function blk():void {
txt.visible = !txt.visible;
tx.visible = !tx.visible;
txt.text = String("You're Lucky This Time");
tx.text = String("You Get 100 Life Points!");
}
}
if(EQUATION==0){
myTimer.stop(); 
var mtIntv:uint = setInterval (blink, 222);
function blink():void {
txt.visible = !txt.visible;
tx.visible = !tx.visible;
txt.text = String("Time's Up!");
tx.text = String("You're Dead!");
}
}
}
```